# Android - Why does onKeyUp trigger a KeyEvent, but onKeyDown does not?

Tags: android, key-events

In my current View, a keyboard is open with numbers 0 to 9, a delete key and an enter key.
I added both an `onKeyDown` and an `onKeyUp` event. Both should log the keycode to the debug console when pressed.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int pKeyCode, KeyEvent pKeyEvent) {
    Log.d("KEYDOWN", pKeyCode+"");
    return true; // also tried false
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int pKeyCode, KeyEvent pKeyEvent) {
    Log.d("KEYUP", pKeyCode+"");
    return true;
}
```

I pressed every single key on the keyboard with the following result:

```
D/KEYUP: 8
D/KEYUP: 9
D/KEYUP: 10
D/KEYUP: 11
D/KEYUP: 12
D/KEYUP: 13
D/KEYUP: 14
D/KEYUP: 15
D/KEYUP: 16
D/KEYDOWN: 67
D/KEYUP: 67
D/KEYUP: 7
D/KEYUP: 66
```

Can someone explain why the keydown event is never triggered for 0-9 and enter? I really need it to trigger when 0-9 are pressed.

> **EDIT:** I added a solution that fixed the issue by replacing both functions with `dispatchKeyEvent`. This doesn't explain why
>   `onKeyDown`didn't recognize those keys, though.
>
> Someone got an answer for this?

Comment: If you perform the same test but with ONLY the keydown event, what do you get?

Comment: just `D/KEYDOWN: 67`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only found a solution to work around this issue, but I did not find the reason WHY this happens in the first place.

This code did the job:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.d("KEYDOWN", event.getKeyCode()+"");
    }
    else if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("KEYUP", event.getKeyCode()+"");
    }
    Log.d("KEY", event.getKeyCode()+"");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What exact View you are using?

Comment: I am quite new to Android, so I actually do not really know how to answer your question @YuriiTsap. I just created a standard project in Android Studio and this is the MainActivity. Don't know what View is used there.

Comment: Please describe your exact problem or what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am logging sensor data during runtime. And in this data log I need to capture what keys are being (if any) pressed for each of the logged data entries. Since, theoretically, more than one data entry could be logged during a key-press, I need both the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events, so I can enable/disable a flag that will then put the corresponding keys into my data entry.

Comment: Have you tried to override EditText and handle this inside of it?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the workflow you need to dive inside the code a little bit, it's not so obvious but nevertheless. Your particular case depends on which view you are extending and the IME. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) :

> In general, the framework cannot guarantee that the key events it delivers to a view always constitute complete key sequences since some events may be dropped or modified by containing views before they are delivered. The view implementation should be prepared to handle FLAG_CANCELED and should tolerate anomalous situations such as receiving a new ACTION_DOWN without first having received an ACTION_UP for the prior key press.

You can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) - this is a good solution, but I'm not aware of your needs. In any case if you are overriding `onKeyDown()` - it will be triggered, and you need to handle it by yourself or call parent implementation. In the case with EditText  - `onKeyDown` will be handled by TextView, despite few cases(Back Button i.e.).